# Java Math.incrementExact(int a) Purpose

Tags: java

Why does [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#incrementExact-int-) exist? What is the difference between

```
int a = 5;
Math.incrementExact(a);
```

and

```
int a = 5;
a++;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What does it do?** It provides a quick way to check for overflow when performing arithmetic on `int` and `long` primitives. In many applications, overflow must be handled carefully. The JavaDoc states:

> Returns the argument incremented by one, throwing an exception if the result overflows an int.

From a mathematical perspective, `2147483647 +1 = 2147483648`. But in Java, `2147483647 +1 = -2147483648`. Arithmetically, this doesn't make sense.

**Why not leave it to the programmer?**
If you didn't have this method (and it's `decrementExact()` counterpart), you would have to add the code similar to the following to your program:

```
    if (a == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("integer overflow");
    } else {
        a ++;
    }
```

**What does the term "exact" mean?** The `Math` package uses "exact" to imply that an `ArithmeticException` is thrown when an overflow occurs. On the other hand, `Math` uses "inexact" to describe methods like `toRadians()` or `toDegrees()` since they produce approximated results, e.g. ones multiplied by `PI=3.141592653589793`.

Comment: That makes sense. What is the meaning of "exact" in its name?

Comment: @MarcB I updated my answer to address the meaning of "exact"

Answer (score 0):

It is there to handle the overflow case.

For the case of an `int`, the max int value is `2147483647`.

So consider this

```
int a = 2147483647;
a+=1;
System.out.println(a);
```

prints out

```
-2147483648
```

where as

```
a = 2147483647;
a = Math.incrementExact(a);
System.out.println(a);
```

throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow
```

**Edit:**
Just saw the other answer which is the same. I'll answer your comment.

The exact goes back to above. It is basically saying that the value returned is guaranteed to be exactly `one` more. Versus the original case where the value was actually a negative number which is **NOT** `1` more. Further more, if you notice, that method only handles `int` and `long`. This is because the precision on those are `exact` as suppose to as `double`s which are not exact.